# Relative entropy (KL divergence) of sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory

Suppose we have two independent random variables, $X$ and $Y$, with different probability distributions.
What is the relative entropy between pdf of $X$ and $X+Y$, i.e.
$$D(P_X||P_{X+Y})$$
assume all support conditions are met.
I know in general pdf of $X+Y$ is convolution of pdf of $X$ and $Y$, but is there 
an easier way to calculate the relative entropy or at least simplify it?

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(t)$ be the PDF of $X$ and $g(t)$ be the PDF of $Y$.
$$D_{KL}(P_X\parallel P_{X+Y}) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\log\frac{f(x)}{(f*g)(x)}\,dx$$
does not admit any obvious simplification, but the term

$$\log\frac{f(x)}{(f*g)(x)}=\log\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)\,\delta(x-t)\,dt}{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)\,g(x-t)\,dt} $$
can be effectively controlled if some informations about the concentration/decay of $g(t)$ are known.

Is this the case?

Comment: g(t) is a uniform PDF over  (-d,d). f(t) is a zero-mean Gaussian PDF.

Comment: What can we say if $g(t)$ is the pdf of a gaussian with $0$ mean and variance $\sigma^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt.

$$D(P_X||P_{X+Y}) = \mathbb{E}[\log \frac{P_X(X)}{P_{X+Y}(X+Y)}] = \mathbb{E}[\log \frac{P_X(X)P_Y(Y)}{P_{X+Y}(X+Y)P_Y(Y)}] \\
= \mathbb{E}[\log \frac{P_X(X)}{P_Y(Y)}] + \mathbb{E}[\log \frac{P_Y(Y)}{P_{X+Y}(X+Y)}] = \infty$$

because $g$ is uniform and has $g(x)=0$ for some $x$ such that $f(x)>0$.

Comment: This is not correct because both terms are $\infty$, so it is: $\infty-\infty\neq \infty.$

Comment: Why is the second term infinity?

Comment: I'd actually guess that $f \ast g$ decays sufficiently fast compared to $f$ as to make the divergence infinite.